# My div fades in properly with show(), but then it jumps up upon animation completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery to animate a fade-in transition for a <div> element that I have. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    function calculate() {
        ...
        if ($("#results").css('display') === 'none') {
            console.log("fadein");
            $("#results").show("normal", function() {
                console.log("animation complete");
            });
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the <div> element I'm fading in:

```
<div id="results">
    <p>Input equation: <span id="eq" class="result"></span></p>
    <p>Roots: <span id="root1" class="result"></span>, <span id="root2" class="result"></span></p>
</div>
```

The fading in effect works perfectly. However, as soon as the animation completes, the element suddenly jumps about 20 pixels up the page. (I could also say that the animation places the element about 20 pixels below its intended location, and then jumps the element up 20 pixels after completion.) How can I fix this?

(I should mention that this jumping bug happens in both Chrome and Firefox)

Edit:

I don't really have much of a style sheet, but here it is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .result {
        color: blue;
    }
    #results {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type="text"] {
        width:50px;
    }
</style>
```

If it's any use at all, here's the entire body of my document, since it's short enough.

```
<body>
    <p><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="input_a" class="variable"/>x^2 +
        <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="input_b" class="variable"/>x +
        <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="input_c" class="variable"/> = 0</p>

    <p><button type="submit" disabled="disabled">Calculate</button>
        <button type="reset">Clear</button></p>

    <div id="results">
        <p>Input equation: <span id="eq" class="result"></span></p>
        <p>Roots: <span id="root1" class="result"></span>, <span id="root2" class="result"></span></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Edit 2: Here's the entire code, since it's not too long: http://pastebin.com/kfjpkSBr

Comment: Does your style sheet define any margin and/or padding for the `results` id? That is often a source of animation issues.

Comment: Can you post the style sheet? I see no problem at the above code

Comment: I don't have much of a stylesheet, but I've edited it in above.

Comment: We will most likely need the HTML around the results div as well.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you add `p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }` to your style sheet?

Comment: @Xenethyl: That "solves" the animation issue, as the div no longer pops upwards. Of course, now everything is bunched up a bit.

Comment: You didn't had any reset stylesheet?

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow: I've run into this issue in the past on various projects. It used to be a bug in jQuery that was supposedly fixed (there's a small example/discussion here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/animation-jump-quick-tip/). If you're using an old version of jQuery, this is likely the same issue. The work-around was to remove margin and padding from the animated element itself (and from elements inside it, I believe). You could replace them with div and/or span spacers. Your `p` elements in `results` sound like the culprit here.

Comment: I'm not sure what a reset stylesheet is, but I believe that I don't have one. Also, I've edited in a link to all of my code, in case some surrounding JavaScript is causing problems.

Comment: A reset style sheet is a set of CSS rules that wipe out and reset all the default values, such as margin and padding, that browsers set on HTML elements. It's useful for projects where you need to ensure that all browsers render identically, because each browser has small (sometimes large) variances between the default CSS values.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your given pastebin. What browser you use?

Comment: @Xenethyl: Thanks for the little tip. I added `padding:0px; margin:0px` to both `#results` and `#results p`, and the little glitch no longer happens.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: I'm primarily using Chrome 13, but it also happened in Firefox 6. According to Xenethyl, the problem seems to be a bug rooted in jQuery itself.

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow: No problem, I'm glad it was an easy fix! I'm sorry that I don't have any more details on the issue. I wasn't able to dig up anything very recent, so I'm kind of puzzled as to why you're experiencing it with a recent jQuery release. In any case, this issue is reminiscent of the jQuery issue where it incorrectly calculated the final dimensions of the element being animated (ie. it over- or undershoots while animating). When the animation completes, the element's size is not the expected size, so there is a small jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the discussion following the original post, the default margin and padding on the `p` elements was determined to cause the jump in animation.

Simply removing the margin and padding from the `p` elements located within the animated `results` element solved the problem. This is likely due to a bug in the animation logic within jQuery that calculates the final desired dimensions of elements that are being animated.

EDIT: Also, just to make note of it, many JS-based animation issues can be solved by giving the animated elements defined dimensions via `width` and `height` CSS properties. Depending on the specific (jQuery) animation being used, and the element it is being applied to, margin and/or padding values may need to be shifted to spacer elements to maintain consistent transitions.